# Ubuntu 20.04: Screen randomly goes black and sometimes logs out

Tags: 20.04, screen, lock-screen, logout

I have an issue where my screen randomly goes black and sometimes logs me out of my session. It sometimes happens every few minutes and multiple times in a row, or sometimes doesn't happen for a few hours.

System:
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
5.11.0-27
Dell Latitude 7280

Empirically, I have noticed that the issue:

1. doesn't seem related to power; the issues occurs whether charging or not
2. doesn't seem related to the screen; the issue occurs regardless of whether my external monitor is connected or not. The issue still occurs if I lower the refresh rate of my primary display (no external monitor connected)

What I would like to do:

1. Investigate whether this is a package, driver, or hardware issue
2. Avoid a complete re-install of the OS

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```shell
sudo systemctl stop systemd-ask-password-wall.service
```

It worked perfectly for me, I'm not getting black screen / logged out anymore.